# how to prevent error in checkShinyVersion?

Tags: r, shiny

My R Shiny App was running fine in R-studio server. But today when I run it in R-studio server, I got an error:

> Error in checkShinyVersion() :    Please upgrade the 'shiny' package
> to (at least) version 1.1

My app.R script has `.libPaths(c('/home/jack/R/SLE_shinyApp/3.5'))` in the beginning, because I intended to set up a dedicated path for this App, so that the packages won't be altered by other R scripts.

So here are all the paths; the 2nd one is the system default R library path which I have no control over.

> > .libPaths()
>
> [1] "/home/jack/R/SLE_shinyApp/3.5" "/app/x86_64/R/v3.5.0/lib64/R/library"

It turns out that `htmlwidgets` package, a dependency of `shiny`, is located only in the 2nd path and was updated by system admin since my last run, thus causing the error.

Here are my solutions and questions:

1. Make R search ONLY `/home/jack/R/SLE_shinyApp/3.5`, so I can install all needed packages and dependencies there. but how to make R search ONLY that path in `app.R`?
2. Update the `shiny` package in `/home/jack/R/SLE_shinyApp/3.5`. But if I run `app.R` line by line, it uses the `shiny v1.1` in `/home/jack/R/SLE_shinyApp/3.5` and runs OK. But if I run `app.R` by clicking "Run App" button, it uses the old shiny in the 2nd path and still gives the error, even with `library(shiny, lib.loc = .libPaths()[1])` following `.libPaths(c('/home/e0380702/R/SLE_shinyApp/3.5'))`.

Can anyone help?

Comment: A hasty google showed that both `htmlwidgets` and `DT` are using that function, are you using either of them?

Comment: Can you restart your R-Studio server session, and try `library(shiny); sessionInfo()` and post that here? My bet is that either: (1) you added a package that depends on a version of Shiny >= 1.1, and that you have an outdated version of `shiny`. Or, (2) you have multiple versions of shiny in your `.libPaths()`, one of which is outdated. In this case, specifying the correct version of `shiny` to use should do the trick. For example, `library(shiny, lib.loc = .libPaths()[1])`, where the number is the path with `shiny` >= 1.1. Let's start by seeing that `sessionInfo()`

Comment: Thanks so much @RichPauloo and r2evans! I've updated my question.